# ¿Cómo Cambiar el color de un DataGridView dependiendo de un tipo boleano de mi base de datos?

Tags: vb6

¿Cómo podría Cambiar el color de una celda de un DataGridView dependiendo de un tipo boleano de mi base de datos? o si un campo de tipo string esta vació o un boleano es 0.

```
    Dim Fecha As Date = fechainical.Text()
    Dim sql As String
    Dim Fecha As Date = fechainical.Text()
    sql = "select (select NOMREP from REPRESEN where CODREP = (select CODREP from CLIENTES where codcli = idreg1))" _
            & " as NOMREP, case WHEN movimiento = 'ALT' THEN" _
            & " 'ALTA' END AS MOVIMIENTO, (select NOMCLI from clientes where codcli = idreg1) as" _
            & " NOMCLI,  fecha from replog where movimiento = 'ALT' and Tabla = 'clientes' and usuario = 'sa' and FECHA >= " & Fecha

    conexion.Consulta(sql, "REPLOG")
    GridVCN.DataSource = conexion.ds.Tables("replog")
```

Comment: Dos preguntas: Utilizas DataTable para llenar el Datasource?, Estas trabajando con ASP.NET?

Comment: Uso dataset y estoy trabajando con Window Form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con la consulta SQL que estas poniendo como ejemplo no puedes evaluar un Boolean por que solo estas retornando la columna `NOMREP` que me imagino que es un string.

Lo primero que debes de hacer es que el DataSource posea los campos que necesitas para evaluar las condiciones, y luego es muy simple como te voy a mostrar en el siguiente ejemplo donde asumo un DataGridView con dos columnas (Nombre y Activo, Vale recordar que la columna Nombre quedaría con índice 0 y la columna Activo con índice 1).

```
   'Se asignan los datos al DataGridView
    GridVCN.DataSource = miDataTable

    'Se recorren las filas del DataGridView
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In GridVCN.Rows
        'Se Evalua que el valor Activo este Falso, en caso correcto se pinta de Rojo
        If Not row.Cells(1).Value Then
            row.Cells(1).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
    Next
```